# How to setState after Map render is completed

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking a way to setState just after the .map completed.

```
const CardList = ({ data, handleTagClick }) =>  {
  return (
    <ul role="list" className="card_list">
      { data.map( ( post, index ) => (
          <Card
            key={`card_${index}`}
            post={post}
            handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
          />
        )          
      )}
    </ul>
  )
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, I want to fire a message to he user when I'm sure the map is completed. Thanks for asking!

Comment: But what does that _mean_? The `.map` completes synchronously, creating an array of elements, then React gets the resulting elements and diffs them with what's currently rendered (if anything) and updates what's rendered (if needed). The user isn't waiting for this (they may be waiting for a fetch to get the `data` to start with,  we've no idea).

Comment: I guess I'm the only one who knows what the user is really waiting for. So, to add more context, as soon the .map completed to display the records, I want to display a message in the screen to the user. My mistake was trying to make the setState inside the .map asking something like 'if (index === data.length)' that of course does not works.

Comment: I'm not sure you do. They'll all get rendered at the same time as everything else in that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const CardList = ({ data, handleTagClick }) => {
const handleAfterMapping = () => {
// Perform your desired state update or action here
// This code will run after the .map function has completed.
// You can access the mapped data and perform any state changes here.
};

return (
<ul role="list" className="card_list">
  {data.map((post, index) => (
    <Card
      key={`card_${index}`}
      post={post}
      handleTagClick={handleTagClick}
    />
  ))}
  {handleAfterMapping()}
</ul>
);
};
```

I do not know if there is any best ways, I think this might help.

Comment: No mention please, that's what developers each other do.